# XML JAXB marshall not saving to xml file

Tags: java, xml, javafx, java-8, jaxb

I have a javafx program that brings up a filechooser to allow a user to pick and image an display it to a grid view with an inserted caption that pops up after an image was pciked. I save both the filepath and the caption to different arraylists [for now] and my goal is to save both to xml file so that I can unmarshall it when the application is re opened so the images would still be there. Right now I just want to be able to save the two strings to an xml file and then figure out the rest later. I am currently able to run my code with no errors until I reach my stop method where I try to save every image and caption the user has added to the array lists.

My JAXB Annotation:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ImageCap {
    private String filePath;
    private String caption;

    public ImageCap() {
    }

    public ImageCap(String filePath, String caption) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.caption = caption;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImageCap{" + "filePath=" + filePath + ", caption=" + caption + '}';
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    @XmlElement
        public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

      public String getCaptions() {
            return caption;
        }

      @XmlElement
        public void setCaption(String caption) {
            this.caption = caption;
        }

    }
```

And my main to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}

  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws JAXBException{

  final JFXPanel bananarama = new JFXPanel();

  //import the library (read))

  // create the (initial) display
  display.makeBrowseButton(primaryStage);
  display.createDisplay(primaryStage);

  // show user
  primaryStage.show();



}@Override
public void stop() throws JAXBException{
  File file = new File("file.xml");
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ImageCap.class);
  Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

//this.context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ImageCap.class);
  //Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
  for(int i = 0; i < display.filePaths.size(); i++)
{
  ImageCap imageCap = new ImageCap();

   imageCap.setFilePath(display.filePaths.get(i));
   imageCap.setCaption(display.captions.get(i).toString());

System.out.println(display.filePaths.get(i).toString());
   try {

   // output pretty printed
   jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

   jaxbMarshaller.marshal(imageCap, file);


       } catch (JAXBException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
       }

  }
}
```

Here are my errors after the stop command:

```
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public void ImageCap.setCaption(java.lang.String)
        at ImageCap
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String ImageCap.caption
        at ImageCap
    Class has two properties of the same name "filePath"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String ImageCap.getFilePath()
        at ImageCap
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.lang.String ImageCap.filePath
        at ImageCap
```

but it specically cuts off at line 81 which is: 
`JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ImageCap.class);`

any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have getter and setters for a field of the same name, then you need to use `XmlAccessType.PROPERTY` rather than `XmlAccessType.FIELD`:

```
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
    public static class ImageCap {
        private String filePath;
        private String caption;
        
...
```

Also, another problem that you will encounter is that you misspelled `getCaption`**`s`**`()` as plural, when it should be `getCaption()`. JAXB will complain about it as well.

Finally, by marshaling your file inside the loop, you are rewriting over and over the same file with the currently processed `imageCap`. If what you want is to marshall all `imageCap`s you need to put them on a `List` and marshall the `List` instead. In order to do that you'd need a new JAXB model class like:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name = "myImageCapList")
    class ImageCapList {
        @XmlElement
        List<ImageCap> imageCap;

        public ImageCapList() {}

        public ImageCapList(List<ImageCap> imageCaps) {
            this.imageCap = imageCaps;
        }
    }
```

and you'd need to create an instance of this object wrapping your list of `ImageCap` objects (`List<ImageCap>`) and use it as the target to invoke the `jaxbMarshaller.marshal` method as shown in the following method:

```
    public void imageCapsMarshal(List<ImageCap> imageCaps, File outFile) {
        try {
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new ImageCapList(imageCaps), outFile);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // HANDLE EXCEPTIONS
        }
    }
```

also, you'll need to instantiate your `JAXBContext` appropriately:

```
    jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ImageCapList.class);
```

The following is a complete working demo of this for you to play with:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class JAXBMarshall {
    
    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Marshaller jaxbMarshaller;

    public JAXBMarshall() throws JAXBException {
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ImageCapList.class);
        jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    }

    public void imageCapsMarshal(List<ImageCap> imageCaps, File outFile) {
        try {
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(new ImageCapList(imageCaps), outFile);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // HANDLE EXCEPTIONS
        }
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBMarshall jaxbMarshaller = new JAXBMarshall();

        File file = new File("file.xml");
        List<ImageCap> imageCaps = IntStream.range(0, 10)
                .mapToObj(idx -> new ImageCap("my/file/path/" + idx, idx + ". The Caption!"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        jaxbMarshaller.imageCapsMarshal(imageCaps, file);
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "myImageCapList")
    static class ImageCapList {
        @XmlElement
        List<ImageCap> imageCap;

        public ImageCapList() {}

        public ImageCapList(List<ImageCap> imageCaps) {
            this.imageCap = imageCaps;
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    static class ImageCap {
        @XmlElement
        String filePath;

        @XmlElement
        String caption;
        
        public ImageCap() {}
        
        public ImageCap(String filePath, String caption) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
            this.caption = caption;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ImageCap{" + "filePath=" + filePath + ", caption=" + caption + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56266915)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thank you that worked! my issue now is that i only get the last item added to my list saved to my xml do you think its a problem with my for loop in my main?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include fixes for this new problem, hope it helps.

Comment: please don't rollback edits to your posts - in the context of a technical description "niceties" like _hope it helps_ are ... noise  ;)